# Downloading by C# with indirect url

Tags: c#, excel, download, stream

I have an indirect link that generates an excel file. I searched a lot and found some methods that did not do what I needed. The link address does not refer to the excel file directly, the cause is that whenever the URL is requested the webpage make a new excel file __refreshes the contents.
I've used different ways which are mentioned below.
What I exactly want to do is that without opening a browser I want to download the content of the URL (which is an excel file) and save that as an excel file.
[Here is the link](http://members.tsetmc.com/tsev2/excel/MarketWatchPlus.aspx?d=0), which if you click on it, you will get an excel file directly, but the URL itself does not contain the extension of excel files.
I have used the following method:

```
client.DownloadFile(@"http://members.tsetmc.com/tsev2/excel/MarketWatchPlus.aspx?d=0", @"D:\a.xlsx");
```

The above method saves the contents but unfortunately it can not be displayed by excel and I do not know the reason.

```
WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(@"http://members.tsetmc.com/tsev2/excel/MarketWatchPlus.aspx?d=0");
using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
{
    Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader r = new StreamReader(responseStream);
    //third party methods
}
```

Also the above code was used by searching but it did not provide what I needed, I used some third party `dlls` to save stream as excel file and again the saved file could not be opened by excel. I also have used Process.Start but it opened the browser. I do not want to open any browser.

Comment: What does the downloaded file contain? Open it with Notepad for example.

Comment: if you enter the url in any browser, an excel file will be downloaded directly. but with the methods that I have used it should be excel file like above. but it's not and I do not know the reason. I did save as text but it did not work.

Comment: Have you tried `request.AllowAutoRedirect=true`? If that doesn't work try using an HTTPWebRequest. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.allowautoredirect%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: thanks. but in the second code section I have referred the mentioned method did not work, unfortunately.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is compressed stream. You should unzip it

```
WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(@"http://members.tsetmc.com/tsev2/excel/MarketWatchPlus.aspx?d=0");
using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
{
    Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    using(var fs = File.Create("MarketWatchPlus-1394.4.24.xlsx"))
    {
        var zipStream = new System.IO.Compression.GZipStream(responseStream,  System.IO.Compression.CompressionMode.Decompress,true);
        zipStream.CopyTo(fs);
    }
}
```

Comment: :-D infact I have registered approximately two hours ago and I do not have 15 reputation to vote.

Comment: @media you are not expected to upvote. Just *accept* the answer. *"Accepting an answer is important as it both rewards posters for solving your problem and informs others that your issue is resolved."*

Answer (score 2):

Credit to EZI for the good answer. Just tossing this out as an alternative. HttpWebRequest does have funcionality for automatic decompression.

```
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(@"http://members.tsetmc.com/tsev2/excel/MarketWatchPlus.aspx?d=0") as HttpWebRequest;
request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip;
using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
{
    using (Stream fs = File.Create("excelFile.xlsx"))
    {
        response.GetResponseStream().CopyTo(fs);
    }
}
```